# Implement "find users in my addressbook" for mobile app

Tags: sql, database, mobile, cloud, nosql

I am building a messaging app, and I am looking to implement the basic functionality where a user can see which people in their phone's address book are already users of the app.

My plan is to have a very simple database of just hashes of all the users phone numbers. Then I could query an array of hashed phone numbers from the user's address book against this database.

What is the best cloud database solution for this task?
Is this best implemented with SQL or NoSQL?

Answer (score 0):

After consulting with a friend who is knowledgeable in this area, he suggested PostgreSQL for this case.